# Django REST Framework: How can I set a FK as optional?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set that a Foreign Key field is optional.

I have already added "null=True, blank=True" to the "group" field in my models.py file but it's also required.

Here is my models.py code:

```
class Record(Timestampable):
  uuid = CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True, editable=False)
  code = CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
  name = CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
  group = ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='members')
```

Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class RecordSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Record
    fields = ('uuid', 'code', 'name', 'group')
```

Comment: Try setting the exclude property in the Meta class to exclude = () and remove fields.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that didn't work for me. The exclude property in Meta class removed the 'group' field but I want it as optional field (not required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you still need to supply the field even if the value is null in your request in DRF.

You can however specify a field as not required:

```
class RecordSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ('uuid', 'code', 'name', 'group')
```

The related documentation is available here: [Django Rest Framework - Serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required)